# How can a case object extend an abstract class?

Tags: scala

I want to have a number of case objects that inherit from a doubly inherited abstract class.

```
object Main {
  sealed abstract class A(a: Int)
  sealed abstract class B(a: Int) extends A(a)

  case object Foo extends B(a) { val a = 5 }

  case class Bar(a: Int) extends A(a)
}
```

However, the line

```
case object Foo extends B(a) { val a = 5 }
```

errors with

```
main.scala:5: error: not found: value a
  case object Foo extends B(a) { val a = 5 }
```

How do I fix my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide an int value for `B`'s constructor. This should work:

```
case object Foo extends B(5) { val a = 5 }
```

In your case, `Foo extends B(0)` would work just as well, since `B` does nothing with that `a` parameter.

Writing `B(a)` requires `a` to be an `Int` value defined in that scope, which is not the case. So it's literally the same as writing:

```
case object Foo extends B(iDontKnowWhatToPutHere)
```